# Função jQuery para seleciona valores em divs e jogar para um array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array

Estou pegando os valores de diversas `<div>`s com o mesmo nome de classe e tentando jogar para um array em jQuery, mas como estou começando na linguagem não estou conseguindo, já pesquisei pela internet e nada que achei me deu uma solução.

Como exemplo:

```js
var array = [];
var count = $('.card-header').length;
var name = $('.card-header').text();
var i, proximo;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  proximo = array.length;
  array[proximo] = name;
}

$('.rodapeCat').text(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="card-header">Casa</span><br>
<span class="card-header">Porta</span><br>
<span class="card-header">Janela</span><br>
<span class="card-header">Escada dos fundos</span><br>
<hr/>

<!--DIV apenas para mostrar se os valores Casa, Porta, Janela, Escada dos fundos estão na array-->
<div class="rodapeCat"><div>
```

Queria que o array ficasse desta forma: `['Casa', 'Porta', 'Janela', 'Escada dos fundos']`.

Alguém teria alguma luz para meu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```js
var array = [];
$('.card-header').each(function(i) {
  array.push($(this).html());
});

$('.rodapeCat').html(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="card-header">Casa</span><br>
<span class="card-header">Porta</span><br>
<span class="card-header">Janela</span><br>
<span class="card-header">Escada dos fundos</span><br>
<hr/>

<!--DIV apenas para mostrar se os valores Casa, Porta, Janela, Escada dos fundos estão na array-->
<div class="rodapeCat"><div>
```

Use [o método `each(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) para iterar os elementos de um seletor do jQuery.

Uma das formas de converter um array em string é com [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Para pegar o conteúdo de uma `<div>` ou então definir esse conteúdo, use [os métodos `html()` e `html(conteudo)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Para adicionar itens em um array sem ter que ficar se preocupando com o tamanho dele, use [o método `push(elemento)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).